# Processes consume more memory every time multiprocessing is started

Tags: python-3.x, memory-leaks, multiprocessing

First of all, I'm very new to Python and this is my first real project.

I have been struggling with an issue I have in a for loop where I iterate over a list of 3 values (regionid) and in each iteration I open up 40 processes using [parrallel_progbar from miniutils](https://miniutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/progress_bar.html#iparallel-progbar) to go through another list of 15000 values (typeid):

```
for regionid in regionid_list:
  print("{}{}".format('Loading market historic data from region: ', regionid))
  market_list = parallel_progbar(   item_history, [(processes, regionid, typeid) for typeid in typeids_list], starmap=True, nprocs=processes, timeout=1)
  print("{}{}".format('Writing to database for regionid: ', regionid))
  con = sql_connection('database.db')
  update_db_values(con, regionid, market_list)
  con.commit()
  con.close()
```

I have monitored my memory with top and my problem is that I can see I have a memory leak. Each time regionid is iterated over, every process opened up requires more memory until at the third iteration I'm out of memory. It starts at 4.5 in the first iteration per proces, then goes to 6 in the second and to 7.5 in the third. I have tried to use gc.collect() after parrallel_progbar is done iterating over typeid as I suspected that could have been the reason, but to no avail. I also tried using iparallel_progbar so it worked as a generator, but again no difference. When parrallel_progbar closes down I can see all the processes are closed down and memory usage drops dramatically as expected. I must admit I really do not know what could be the issue, so I guess I'm looking for some hints on how I can fix it. As this is also my first post here I hope I have provided enough information, otherwise please do ask me. The function I call in the for-loop is pasted at the bottom of this post

*EDIT1: Also I should add, that when the python script is closed down and restarted from the beginning. all the issues are reset ie. it takes all three iterations to get to the memory problem. I also tried just the last iteration of regionid alone anbd that causes no problem by itself*

*EDIT2: Here are screenshots from running top while the script is executing. the images to left are during the iteration of regionid. and on the two on the top right are after first and second iteration and the processes are closed down again and data is written to the database. The bottom right is at the crash where available memory is basically 0*
[dumps of top from running the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SqmE.jpg)

The function I call for every value in typeid is:

```
def item_history(processes, RegionID, TypeID):
#CONSTRUCT THE URL TO CALL
Datasource = 'tranquility'
url = 'https://esi.evetech.net/latest/markets/'

url_final = url + RegionID +'/history/'
payload = {'datasource': Datasource, 'type_id': TypeID}

#SET PARAMETERS AND DECLARE VARIABLES
counter = 0
volume_summation = 0
market_value_summation = 0.0
vol_median_list = []
average_list = []
size_median_list = []
high_median_list = []
low_median_list = []
spread_median_list = []

week = 7
month = 30
quarter = 90
year = 365

error_buffer = 1
error_list = [400, 404, 420, 422, 500, 503, 504, 520]
#CALL THE URL AND RECEIVE RESPONSE

try:
    response = requests.get(
        url_final,
        params = payload
        )
except:
    null_response = null_return(TypeID, RegionID, "{}{}".format('ERROR: ', requests.exceptions))
    return null_response
if response:
    #print('Succes')
    history = json.loads(response.text)
    if not history:
        #print('Returned nothing')
        null_response = null_return(TypeID, RegionID, "Null")
        return null_response
    else:
        #con = sql_connection()
        history.reverse()
        history_length = len(history)
        
        last_updated = ''
        volume_yesterday = 0
        market_value_yesterday = 0
        volume_week_med = 0
        market_value_week_med = 0
        volume_month_med = 0
        market_value_month_med = 0
        volume_quarter_med = 0
        market_value_quarter_med = 0
        volume_year_med = 0
        market_value_year_med = 0
        high_yesterday = 0
        high_week_med = 0
        high_month_med = 0
        high_quarter_med = 0
        high_year_med = 0
        low_yesterday = 0
        low_week_med = 0
        low_month_med = 0
        low_quarter_med = 0
        low_year_med = 0
        spread_yesterday = 0
        spread_week_med = 0
        spread_month_med = 0
        spread_quarter_med = 0
        spread_year_med = 0
        _52w_low = 0
        _52w_high = 0

        for history_item in history:
            volume = history_item['volume']
            average = float(history_item['average'])
            size = float(volume) * float(average)
            date = str(history_item['date'])
            high = float(history_item['highest'])
            low = float(history_item['lowest'])
            spread = high - low
            
            vol_median_list.append(volume)
            average_list.append(average)
            size_median_list.append(size)
            high_median_list.append(high)
            low_median_list.append(low)
            spread_median_list.append(spread)
            
            volume_summation = volume_summation + int(volume)
            market_value_summation = market_value_summation + (float(volume) * float(average))
            
            if counter == 0:
                last_updated = date
                volume_yesterday = "{:.2f}".format(volume)
                market_value_yesterday = "{:.2f}".format(size)
                high_yesterday = "{:.2f}".format(high)
                low_yesterday = "{:.2f}".format(low)
                spread_yesterday = "{:.2f}".format(spread)
                
            elif counter == week - 1:
                volume_week_med = "{:.2f}".format(statistics.median(vol_median_list))
                market_value_week_med = "{:.2f}".format(statistics.median(size_median_list))
                high_week_med = "{:.2f}".format(statistics.median(high_median_list))
                low_week_med = "{:.2f}".format(statistics.median(low_median_list))
                spread_week_med = "{:.2f}".format(statistics.median(spread_median_list))
                _52w_low = "{:.2f}".format(min(average_list))
                _52w_high = "{:.2f}".format(max(average_list))
                
            elif counter == month - 1:
                volume_month_med = "{:.2f}".format(statistics.median(vol_median_list))
                market_value_month_med = "{:.2f}".format(statistics.median(size_median_list))
                high_month_med = "{:.2f}".format(statistics.median(high_median_list))
                low_month_med = "{:.2f}".format(statistics.median(low_median_list))
                spread_month_med = "{:.2f}".format(statistics.median(spread_median_list))
                _52w_low = "{:.2f}".format(min(average_list))
                _52w_high = "{:.2f}".format(max(average_list))
                
            elif counter == quarter - 1:
                volume_quarter_med = "{:.2f}".format(statistics.median(vol_median_list))
                market_value_quarter_med = "{:.2f}".format(statistics.median(size_median_list))
                high_quarter_med = "{:.2f}".format(statistics.median(high_median_list))
                low_quarter_med = "{:.2f}".format(statistics.median(low_median_list))
                spread_quarter_med = "{:.2f}".format(statistics.median(spread_median_list))
                _52w_low = "{:.2f}".format(min(average_list))
                _52w_high = "{:.2f}".format(max(average_list))
                
            elif counter == year - 1:
                volume_year_med = "{:.2f}".format(statistics.median(vol_median_list))
                market_value_year_med = "{:.2f}".format(statistics.median(size_median_list))
                high_year_med = "{:.2f}".format(statistics.median(high_median_list))
                low_year_med = "{:.2f}".format(statistics.median(low_median_list))
                spread_year_med = "{:.2f}".format(statistics.median(spread_median_list))
                _52w_low = "{:.2f}".format(min(average_list))
                _52w_high = "{:.2f}".format(max(average_list))
                break
            
            counter = counter + 1
            result_list = [ TypeID,
                            last_updated,
                            volume_yesterday,
                            volume_week_med,
                            volume_month_med,
                            volume_quarter_med,
                            volume_year_med,
                            market_value_yesterday,
                            market_value_week_med,
                            market_value_month_med,
                            market_value_quarter_med,
                            market_value_year_med,
                            high_yesterday,
                            high_week_med,
                            high_month_med,
                            high_quarter_med,
                            high_year_med,
                            low_yesterday,
                            low_week_med,
                            low_month_med,
                            low_quarter_med,
                            low_year_med,
                            spread_yesterday,
                            spread_week_med,
                            spread_month_med,
                            spread_quarter_med,
                            spread_year_med,
                            _52w_low,
                            _52w_high]
        
        #update_db_values(con, RegionID, result_list)
        #con.commit()
        #con.close()
        return result_list
else:
    try:
        if response.headers:
            Error_remain = int(response.headers['x-esi-error-limit-remain'])
            Error_reset = int(response.headers['x-esi-error-limit-reset'])
            Error_sleep = Error_reset + 1
        
            if (Error_remain <= processes + error_buffer) and (int(response.status_code) in error_list):
                print("{}{}{}{}{}{}".format('Errors remaining: ', Error_remain,' Will sleep for ', Error_sleep, 's for itemid: ', TypeID))
                time.sleep(Error_sleep)
    except:
        print("{},{}".format('Exception occured with header for ItemID: ', TypeID))
    null_response = null_return(TypeID, RegionID, "{}{}".format('ERROR: ', response.status_code))
    #print("{}{}{}{}".format('ItemID: ', TypeID, ' returns ERROR: ', response.status_code))
    return null_response
```

Comment: What makes you think there is a memory leak, as I understand it, each process you start consumes memory?  This would not be considered a memory leak, since the memory consumed is in direct relationship to the number of processes

Comment: Because every time my parrallel_progbar terminates all the processes do to. It might not be a memory leak par se (I don't know what else to call it), but something makes the next batch of processes that start up when regionid iterates consume more memory than the previous  batch despite them running over basically more of the same type of data with the same function

Comment: I've added screenshots of top while the script is running and a bit of extra info in my edits on the original post